# SQL percentage format issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL code which has no syntax errors but it returns an empty sheet (below).

Works fine without lines 13 to 19 where I transfer the Saving into a % and turning negative values to 0.

Hope someone could advise.

```
Select Distinct rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.project_title As Title,
  rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.department As Department,
  rptviewContract.AwardedDateTime As Award,
  rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value As Budget,
  Convert(decimal,Replace(rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', '')) As Value,
  Case
    When rptviewContract.estimated_value -
    Convert(decimal,Replace(rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', '')) <=
    0 Then 0
    Else rptviewContract.estimated_value -
    Convert(decimal,Replace(rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))
  End As Saving,
  Case
    When (Format(((rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value -
    Convert(decimal,Replace(rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))) /
    rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value), 'p')) <= 0 Then 0
    Else (Format(((rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value -
    Convert(decimal,Replace(rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))) /
    rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value), 'p')) End As [%]
From rptviewGovtTransparencyCode
  Inner Join rptviewContract On rptviewContract.contract_id =
    rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.contract_id
  Inner Join rptviewCustomField On rptviewCustomField.OrgId =
    rptviewContract.OrgId
  Inner Join rptviewCustomFieldAnswer On rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.TargetAreaId =
    rptviewContract.project_id And rptviewCustomField.Id =
    rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.CustomFieldId
  Inner Join rptviewContractPrimaryContact On rptviewContract.contract_id =
    rptviewContractPrimaryContact.ContractId
Where rptviewContract.AwardedDateTime >= '2018-04-01' And
  rptviewCustomField.Title = 'awarded value'
Order By Title
```

Previously, lines 13 to 19 of the above were represented as

```
Format(((rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value -
  Convert(decimal,Replace(rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))) /
  rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.estimated_value), 'p') As [%]
```

But it still was not clear as how to replace negative % values with 0s.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Certainly you can simplify the query if your question is really just about a formatting issue.

Comment: Well, it is basically our database hence these dodgy names of the lines. But the functions and clauses are still the same as generally. Would it help if I renamed the lines to "1", "2", etc.?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, all I really wanted is to "Saving / Budget" in % format but not sure what is the best way to do it. The query I have done works but does not bring any results so clearly something went wrong. But I cannot understand what exactly.

Comment: As noted, please tag this with the database product you are using.
Please carefully examine the contents of rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer looking for places where the value is not numeric.
I'm just guessing that the datatype of Answer is other than numeric, and you store a string representation of the number, which is why you need to convert it.
If the value is not numeric, you will have problems exactly as outlined in your description - What does convert return if it can't convert the value?. How these will manifest themselves is dependent upon the database product your are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server, the issue is the placement of the FORMAT wrapper. FORMAT returns NVARCHAR, so your <=0 isn't behaving as expected. Put the CASE inside the FORMAT, as below (using column aliases, because, well, one should):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  gtc.project_title AS Title
 ,gtc.department AS Department
 ,c.AwardedDateTime AS Award
 ,gtc.estimated_value AS Budget
 ,CONVERT(DECIMAL, REPLACE(cfa.Answer, ',', '')) AS Value
 ,CASE
    WHEN c.estimated_value - CONVERT(DECIMAL, REPLACE(cfa.Answer, ',', '')) <= 0 THEN 0
    ELSE c.estimated_value - CONVERT(DECIMAL, REPLACE(cfa.Answer, ',', ''))
  END AS Saving
 ,FORMAT(CASE WHEN ((gtc.estimated_value - CONVERT(DECIMAL, REPLACE(cfa.Answer, ',', ''))) / gtc.estimated_value) <= 0 
                THEN 0
              ELSE ((gtc.estimated_value - CONVERT(DECIMAL, REPLACE(cfa.Answer, ',', ''))) / gtc.estimated_value)
         END, 'p') 
  AS [%]
FROM
  rptviewGovtTransparencyCode AS gtc
  INNER JOIN
    rptviewContract AS c
      ON
      c.contract_id = gtc.contract_id
  INNER JOIN
    rptviewCustomField AS cf
      ON
      cf.OrgId = c.OrgId
  INNER JOIN
    rptviewCustomFieldAnswer AS cfa
      ON
      cfa.TargetAreaId = c.project_id
      AND cf.Id = cfa.CustomFieldId
  INNER JOIN
    rptviewContractPrimaryContact AS cpc
      ON
      c.contract_id = cpc.ContractId
WHERE
  c.AwardedDateTime >= '2018-04-01'
  AND cf.Title = 'awarded value'
ORDER BY
  Title;
```

Comment: Thank you Eric for all the input. I will certainly use aliases going forward as they do seem simpler than full names. In does seem like it is SQL Server but I am very new to this, few weeks in, so was not sure.
Just a clarification, lines 11-13 of your query, do all the brackets stay as supposed to? The system I use says that there is an error in line 12, position 14 - unexpected token "," before 'p'. I tried to fix the brackets but it does not seem to work. Hope you could advise.

Comment: Oops, position 114*

Comment: @Vladislav, sorry about that. I missed the END on the CASE statement. Edited query is above.

Comment: Thank you Eric, that now works perfectly. Lesson learnt - do Aliases and do not forget to end a case clause! :)

Comment: Table aliases aren’t absolutely necessary, but they improve readability when you have long table names. It’s good that you added table names to all of your columns, though. That also helps so you can tell where each item comes from. You’re doing fine so far. :)